# Invoke nested shell scripts from ssh

Tags: shell, scripting, ssh

I have two shell scripts; let's call those script1 and script2.

Within script1 I invoke script2. When I call script1 from my local terminal it work fine, but when I launch this command by ssh like this:

```
plink.exe -ssh hostname -l user -pw password "path to script1/script1"
```

I get this error:

> script2 not found.

Now I can put an absolute path inside script1 to call script2, but the problem is that script2 calls other scripts and so on...

Can I avoid ssh look for a command from root?

Answer (score 1):

In script1, try if adding this at the start of script helps:

```
cd $(dirname "$0")
```

Or call pushd/popd around calls to script2.

```
pushd $(dirname "$0")
relative_path_for_script2/script2 arg1 arg2 ...
popd
```

If while calling manually from terminal, you need to execute the `script1` from a specific directory, say `/tmp`, `pushd` that directory instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`PATH`](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/cs348/unix_path.html) in `script1` or in the code which invokes it.